# How to fix my SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO MGT2ITX_IMPORT_TXN_DETAIL_3DS (IMPORT_TXN_DETAIL_ID, IMPORT_TXN_HEADER_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE, DUPLICATE_FLAG, 
        TRANSACTION_LOG_TIMESTAMP, 
        FIELD_01, FIELD_02, FIELD_03, FIELD_04, FIELD_05, 
        FIELD_08, FIELD_09, FIELD_10, FIELD_11, FIELD_12, 
        FIELD_13, FIELD_14, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, IS_DELETED)
VALUES (192, 2, 'T', 'N', (convert(datetime,'08/16/2017 14:59:43', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), 
        '3009', '4215849500108603', '000025', '950212563', 'TEST EPAYMENT', 
        '20170816 14:59:43', '1.0.0', '103.216.96.5', 'https://auth.lsswebuat.itmx.co.th:8101/itmx/authenticateresponse', '21.00', 
        'THB', '103.216.96.5', convert(datetime,'08/25/2017 15:01:57', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'SYSTEM', 'N')
```

and I get this error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MGT2ITX_IMPORT_TXN_DETAIL_3DS'.

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: please format your code, tell us your DBMS and what you have tried to fix it so far

Comment: It's SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

I think that `CONVERT` call is causing the insert to choke.  The good news is that I don't think you need it.  If you want to insert a timestamp, you can do so directly as a string, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO MGT2ITX_IMPORT_TXN_DETAIL_3DS (
    IMPORT_TXN_DETAIL_ID,
    IMPORT_TXN_HEADER_ID,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE,
    DUPLICATE_FLAG,
    TRANSACTION_LOG_TIMESTAMP,
    ...
)
VALUES (192, 2, 'T', 'N', '2017-08-16 14:59:43', ...)
```

**Peter's edit:**

There is a second `CONVERT` call which also needs to be changed.  Replace this:

```
convert(datetime,'08/16/2017 14:59:43', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

with this:

```
'2017-08-16 14:59:43'
```

Comment: Note that there are two `CONVERT()` calls that should be removed / replaced with just the datetime strings.